# Get latest object from S3 bucket?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket with thousands of objects in it. Is there a way I could get latest object (last created) from this bucket? I am using AWS Java SDK.

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to list all the objects and pick out the one with the most recent date.

If this is something you will continually need in the future, you might want to look into sending S3 events to Lambda.